# Adding values from DictReader to empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a rock climbing simulator game for fun.  Below is a function from the program, which works. But I can't help but think it could be refactored or more pythonic.

Namely, I open the data with `csv.DictReader` and read through the data, which add to a blank dictionary called route_info.  Is this step necessary?

The function has a with-open block, which opens a .csv file, but a link to the data is [here](https://github.com/epurpur/Seneca-Gumbies/blob/master/SenecaGumbiesCode/seneca_routes.csv).

```
import csv
import time


routes_climbed = []
pitches_climbed = 0

def choose_route():
    """After deciding about the weather, you come here and choose a 
    route to climb. Reads list of routes from .csv file with names, 
    grades, and pitches."""

    global routes_climbed, pitches_climbed

    route_info = {}

    with open('seneca_routes.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:     #weird encoding from excel?
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, ('route_name', 'route_grade', 'pitches'))
        print("Choose a route to climb from the following list of classics.")
        print()

        for row in reader:
            print(row['route_name'],row['route_grade'])
            route_info[row['route_name']] = row['pitches']

    route_choice = input("Which route do you want to climb? : ")

    if route_choice in route_info.keys():
        routes_climbed.append(route_choice)
        pitches_climbed += int(route_info[route_choice])
        climb_route(route_choice)
    else:
        print("Incorrect route name")
        time.sleep(3)
        choose_route()

choose_route()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Pass the code through at least one linter such as pycodestyle or flake8 to get more idiomatic Python.
2. Don't use `global`. Returning two values, while ugly, is preferable to having global state.
3. You can add `\n` to the end of a string to print a newline, avoiding empty `print()`s.
4. Use `argparse` to rather than `input()` to make the script … well, scriptable.
5. Each route should probably be an object rather than a disparate set of just stuff, even though these objects will have no methods for now.
6. Using a `main` method as the entry point for the functionality would make the script usable by other scripts.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm thinking about how to not use global.  Would a class be a better way to do this?  What would you suggest?

Comment: The very simplest thing you could do is simply move the declaration of the current globals into your function - they aren't referenced outside the function, after all. This code does look like it could be made clearer through OO, but that could easily be a separate refactoring.

Comment: I can do that, however, I have different functions (not included here) that are affecting the global variables. For example, once I choose a route I go to the climb_route() function. In climb_route() I ask "Do you want to climb another", if so then I return to choose_route().  So I'd be overwriting my routes_climbed and pitches_climbed variables.  

Just so I know better in the future, should I include my entire program in code review?

Comment: It depends what you want to be reviewed. I just see two globals which clearly don't need to be; with the rest of the code it might be much more obvious how to refactor it.